# Implementing numerical integration

Tags: c++, performance, c++11, numerical-methods

I have this C++ code that implements a rectangular numerical integration.  It evaluates the \$K\$-dimensional integral

$$\int_{u_K = 0}^{\gamma}\int_{u_{K-1} = 0}^{\gamma-u_K}\cdots\int_{u_2}^{\gamma-u_K-\cdots-u_3}F_U(\gamma-\sum_{k=2}^Ku_k)f_U(u_2)\cdots f_U(u_K)\,du_2\cdots du_K$$
where \$F_U\$ is the cdf and \$f_U\$ is the pdf.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

float pdf(float u){
     return (1/(pow(1+u, 2)));
}

float cdf(float u){
      return (1 - 1/(u+1));
}
// The main function that implements the numerical integration, 
//and it is a recursive function
float integ(float h, int k, float du){
      float res = 0;
      if (k == 1){
         res =  cdf(h);
      }else{
         float u = 0;
      while (u < h){
         res += integ(h - u, k - 1, du)*pdf(u)*du;
         u += du;
     }
}
     return res;
}

int main(){
    float du = 0.0001;
    int K = 3;
    float gamma[4] = {0.31622777, 0.79432823, 
                1.99526231, 5.01187234};
    int G = 50;
    int Q = 2;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        if ((G-Q*(K-1)) > 0){
            float gammath = (gamma[i]/Q)*(G-Q*(K-1));
            cout<<1-integ(gammath, K, du)<< endl;
    }

 }

    return 0;
}
```

I am facing a speed problem, although I switched to C++ from Python and MATLAB, because C++ is faster. The problem is that I need a small step size `du` to get an  accurate evaluation of the integration.

Basically, I want to evaluate the integral at 4 different points defined by gammath, which is a function of other defined parameters.

Is there anyway I can speed up this program? I already have 25x+ speed factor over the same code in Python, but still the code takes too long (I ran it all night, and it wasn't finished in the morning). And this is only for K=3, and G=50. In other cases I want to test K = 10, and G = 100 or 300.

Comment: Do you compile with -O3?

Comment: @JVApen Sorry, I am not familiar with what that is. I am not new to C++, but I don't use it normally. I use the CodeLite IDE, and I believe the compiler is g++ MinGW .

Comment: `-Ox` simply refers to compiler optimizations possible on gcc. [Here is a short overview](https://www.rapidtables.com/code/linux/gcc/gcc-o.html)

Comment: @vnp I want to evaluate the K-dimensional integral $$\int_{u_K = 0}^{\gamma}\int_{u_{K-1} = 0}^{\gamma-u_K}\cdots\int_{u_2}^{\gamma-u_K-\cdots-u_3}F_U(\gamma-\sum_{k=2}^Ku_k)f_U(u_2)\cdots f_U(u_K)\,du_2\cdots du_K$$ where $$F_U$$ is the cdf and $$f_U$$ is the pdf.

Comment: @BlackMath: That's perfect.  I've added that explanation to the question for you.

Comment: @TobySpeight I will try `x*x` instead of `pow(x, 2)`. Exactly, there should be a parallelization opportunity, but not sure how it can be done. Do you any suggestion on how this might be done?

Comment: I'd boot Linux [per your comment below] in 64 bit mode. You don't need 64 bit addresses, but this mode gives you 16 [or so] integer registers and double the number of XMM [floating point] hardware registers. In addition to parallelism, there is also vectorization (e.g. `for (i = 0;  i < 10;  ++i) z[i] = x[i] * y[i];` might be able to do four multiplies in a single XMM/SIMD instruction and the number of loop iterations would be reduced by 4x). The compiler with the right `-f*` or (e.g. `-O3`) options may try to do this automatically

Comment: @Graig Interesting. I will try this. I don't need to install anything on Linux. The gcc compiler comes with the OS, right?

Comment: Because `gcc` is used a lot (i.e. to rebuild kernel or sometimes to do just-in-time compile/link for some stuff) its package will _probably_ be pre-installed after installing ubuntu. Otherwise, something similar to `sudo apt install gcc`. If not, google `"install gcc" ubuntu` or use SE's ubuntu site to ask ubuntu related questions

Comment: @CraigEstey OK, I will switch to Linux, and try it there. Thanks

Comment: Your integral runs 0 to gamma, and it seems like it should do so with a step size du, but the code is using du against gammath, not gamma. What is gammath?

Answer (score 11):

I see a few things that may help you improve your program.

### Avoid `pow` for `float`

The use of `pow` converts the argument to a `double` and returns a `double`.  If you're casting the result to a `float` anyway, the use of `std::powf` would be more appropriate.  But see the next suggestion for an even better approach.

### Prefer multiplication to `pow` with small, fixed integral powers

The content of the `pdf` function could be rewritten like this instead:

```
 return 1.0f/((u+1)*(u+1));
```

### Usealittlemorewhitespace

With everything crowded together on the line, it's hard to read and understand some lines like this:

```
float gammath = (gamma[i]/Q)*(G-Q*(K-1));
```

I'd write it like this instead:

```
float gammath{gamma[i] / Q) * (G - Q * (K - 1)};
```

This also uses the C++11 uniform initialization syntax, which I prefer.

### Use `constexpr` where appropriate

Any time you can make a numerical constant or expression `constexpr` is one more opportunity for compiler optimization.  In this case, virtually everything in `main`, including `du`, `K`, `gamma`, `G`, and `Q` can be made `constexpr` simply by adding that keyword in front of the declaration.  With that, the compiler is free to evaluate expressions like this:

```
G - Q * (K - 1)
```

once at compile-time rather than at runtime.  It can save quite a bit of time if you use it.

### Move invariants out of the loop

The value of the expression listed above does not change within the loop (or within the program at all, as presented).  Smart compilers can usually optimize that by themselves, but doing it manually may give you insight.  For example, we can make a constant of that expression outside the loop:

```
constexpr auto m{G - Q * (K - 1)};
```

Now the inner `if` boils down to `if (m > 0)` but since it's invariant within the loop, move it outside.  Now we have the encapsulating `if` *outside* and the `for` loop *inside* which makes a lot more sense.

### Use C++11 threading features

The calculations for each value of `gamma` are completely independent.  For that reason, they could easily be calculated in parallel.  Here's a way to do that:

```
int main() {
    constexpr float du = 0.0001;
    constexpr int K = 3;
    constexpr float gamma[4] = {0.31622777, 0.79432823, 1.99526231, 5.01187234};
    constexpr int G = 50;
    constexpr int Q = 2;
    constexpr auto m{G - Q * (K - 1)};
    std::vector<std::future<float>> chunks;
    if (m > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            float gammath{gamma[i] / Q * m};
            chunks.push_back(std::async(integ, gammath, K, du));
        }
    }
    std::mutex cout_mutex;
    for (int i=0; i < 4; ++i) {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(cout_mutex);
        std::cout << gamma[i] << '\t' << 1 - chunks[i].get() << '\n';
    }
}
```

This requires `<future>`, `<mutex>`, and `<vector>` as `#include`s.

### Parallelize the recursive integrals

If there are 100,000 steps in the integral, why do that with a single core?  If you have a multicore machine like I do, you could divide that work among multiple cores by using the same kind of `std::async` technique shown above.  This would dramatically speed the results (and can be divided among as many cores as you have).  I did not implement that, but the code above should give a hint as to how to do such a thing generically.

### Use `static` for functions which can have file scope

If the `pdf`, `cdf` and `integ` functions are never used outside the file in which they're defined, the compiler can get quite clever about inlining code and other optimizations.  For that reason, I'd recommend making those functions `static` if at all possible.

### Results

I didn't have the patience to run this at the `du` value in the program (0.0001) so I ran it at 50 times that at 0.005 to speed up testing.  Obviously, that's an option if you can accept the lower resolution, but I just did it to speed up timing tests.

The original (with the modified value of `du`) took 1.06 seconds, while the modified version took 0.723s.  At full resolution (`du = 0.0001`) the results took 30 minutes and 3 seconds on the same 64-bit 8-core Linux machine.

Comment: Why would you use the Lockguard?

Comment: The `lock_guard` is used to prevent the results from being intermixed as they are printed.  With two `gamma` values very numerically close, they could finish at nearly the same time and without the `lock_guard` the output might be interleaved.

Comment: `std::pow` is overloaded for `float`, so won't promote argument or result to `double`.  It's still a poor choice when the exponent is a small integer, of course.

Comment: @Edward: I don't get is, the mutex is local and your printing happens single threaded

Comment: @TobySpeight: absolutely right.  As I mentioned in my answer, the gain there is primarily human insight rather than compiler optimization.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and for the comments to make the code clearer. I am not an expert in C++, and many of this stuff is new to me (I am trying to use C++ for speeding up a program). I will have to read more about multi-threading. However, when I used your code, and run it, it gives me this error: `invalid use of of incomplete type class std::future<float>`, and gives the error at this line `chunks.push_back(std::async(integ, gammath, K, du));` inside the for loop. Is it a problem in the compiler I am using, or there is something wrong in the code itself? Thanks

Comment: A speed factor of 1.4 isn't much. The code will still be too slow at that rate. I was hoping for a 30x+ factor. The resolution of 0.001 isn't enough to give accurate evaluation, not even 0.0001, I think. But I would need to test it.

Comment: @BlackMath: you'll need to have compiler support for at least C++11 (that is, the 2011 version of the standard and libraries) and also to have a line that says `#include <future>`.  On Linux (where I'm testing) one also needs to link with the `pthread` library.

Comment: @Edward I have C++14 compiler MinGW, I think. I included all you have mentioned: <future>, <mutex>, and <vector>. OK, now I saw you did the full resolution. 30 minutes is actually very good. My machine is i5 with 4 cores (I suppose), so, I think it would be slower. I will need to have the code works first to test it.

Comment: @Edward I kept the functions (pdf, cdf, and integ) the same, except for the power in the pdf function. Do I have to change the type or anything in these functions for the `main` function to work?

Comment: If you have OpenMP, @TobySpeight's answer is also definitely worth trying either by itself or in combination with this.  Knowing how to judiciously use the C++ threading library is a great skill to have, but OMP can often get you huge benefits, too, without much effort required on your part!

Comment: @BlackMath: I'd suspect a linker problem.  See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45565412/invalid-use-of-incomplete-type-using-stdfuture) for a similar problem and possible solution.

Comment: @Edward It appears that MinGW doesn't support multi-threading automatically. What other compilers I can use that support multi-threading without any configuration?

Comment: Good answer, except for the recommendation of `static`: it doesn't affect function call inlining. And for the purpose of declaring linkage it's a C-ism. In C++, we use unnamed namespaces and `inline` in its stead.

Comment: @Konrad: `static` is just as valid as anonymous namespaces - there's no clear benefit of one over the other for a program such as this.  `inline` is less relevant - usually, compilers make their own decisions about whether to inline functions these days; `inline` is mostly useful when you want to avoid violating ODR (and very occasionally when you want to prevent making function pointers).  I'd say your comment is more a style preference than an absolute fact.

Comment: @TobySpeight You're right that it's just as valid but there's a clear stylistic preference in C++ (as is spacing — this is Code Review, after all). As for `inline`, I wasn't talking about inlineability but you're right that it doesn't affect the symbol's external visibility so it's not the right tool here.

Comment: @Edward, you might be interested in [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_syncbuf) and [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_osyncstream). They seem to be merged into C++20 already. Dunno about implementation status though.

Comment: @Incomputable: I didn't know about `std::basic_osyncstream` before your note.  I have a couple of projects that could benefit from using it, and will watch for when it's implemented in `libstdc++`.

Comment: @Edward, I personally don't have high hopes about it. fmtlib has very high chances to come in C++20, as user defined class objects as template arguments were merged too. That would let it outperform `printf` in theory.

Answer (score 7):

## Improve robustness and readability

- Don't `using namespace` with namespaces not designed for it.
- Use `const` and `constexpr` to make your intent clear and prevent silly accidents.
- Make your internal functions `static`.
- Use more whitespace around operators.

## Improve performance

I started with your code as a baseline, but increased `du` tenfold (to `.001`) to be able to test in a reasonable amount of time.  I compiled with `g++ -std=c++17 -O3 -march=native` to allow the optimiser to use its full range of substitutions and to use the full capabilities of the machine.

`std::pow()` normally works by multiplying logarithms.  For a power of 2, it's much simpler to simply multiply a number by itself.  I got about 10% speed improvement by re-writing `pdf()` thus:

```
static float pdf(float u)
{
    return 1 / ((1+u)*(1+u));
}
```

Note that the seemingly equivalent `return 1 / (1+u) / (1+u)` provided exactly zero improvement, because the cost of division is so high.  (Which obviously suggests `std::pow(1+u, -2)` as an alternative, but I recommend the version I shown above, as it's more accurate).

Are you sure you want to use `float`?  If `double` is slower on your platform, it may still be a worthwhile trade-off if it allows you to use a larger value of `du`.

You can parallelize the loop in `main()`, like this (add `-fopenmp` to your `g++` command):

```
    float result[4] = {};
    constexpr auto gqk = G - Q*(K-1);

#pragma omp parallel for
    for (int i = 0;  i < 4;  ++i) {
        if (gqk > 0) {
            result[i] = 1-integ(gamma[i]*gqk/Q, K, du);
        }
    }

    for (auto r: result) {
        std::cout << r << std::endl;
    }
```

That saves me another 25% or so in wall-clock time (at the expense of using more CPU cores).

However, you'll get a much better improvement by parallelizing the  loop in `integ` instead:

```
static float integ(float h, int k, float du)
{
    if (k == 1) {
        return cdf(h);
    }

    float res = 0;
    const int iterations = h / du;

#pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:res)
    for (int i = 0;  i < iterations;  ++i) {
        const float u = i * du;
        res += integ(h - u, k - 1, du) * pdf(u) * du;
    }

    return res;
}
```

(We need the `reduction` clause so that all the threads can contribute to `res` without needing to synchronize for that step - OpenMP applies the reduction after the threads have each produced their own local sum).

That gained about 80% improvement over the original, on this 8-core machine.  (9 seconds elapsed with du = .001, and 15m 6s with du = .0001.  You're still going to have severe scaling problems when K goes to 10 - you'll probably need to also apply some mathematical insight to reduce the complexity at this point).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am not a professional programmer, so, thanks for clarifying how to make my code clearer. I am learning. 15m6s for du=0.0001 is fantastic. What do I need to use OpenMP? I use MinGW compiler, and it seems it doesn't support multi-threading because it is cross platform or something. Also I have to say I am using it on Windows not Linux.

Comment: I'm using GCC on Linux, and for that I just needed to add `-fopenmp` to my command line, as shown.  I don't know how MinGW differs, so I'm not qualified to help there, I'm afraid (other than to recommend that you check you have a recent version, but I expect you've already thought of that!).  I don't know whether you could write an on-topic [so] question (with a minimal C++&OpenMP program and a "*How do I make MinGW compile this to parallel code?*").  You'd have to be careful with the wording there.

Comment: Would using `res += (((k - 1) == 1) ? cdf(h) : integ(h - u, k - 1, du)) * pdf(u) * du;` add anything? This saves the extra call to `integ` when it's just going to use `cdf`. If `K` is always guaranteed to be greater than 1, the `if (k == 1)` at the top could be eliminated as well.

Comment: You're probably right @Craig - I have to leave now, but perhaps you could try your suggestion and post it as another answer if it turns out to be helpful?

Comment: @Toby I actually has Ubuntu as a dual boot on my laptop. I think gcc is already installed and part of the Linux OS, right? @Graig `k` is always greater than or equal to 1.

Comment: Sorry, but I am confused here. You said that you complied using `g++ -std=c++17 -O3 -march=native`, but then said to compile with `gcc -fopenmp`. Which one is it? Say I have my code saved in a file called numericint.cpp, what should I write in the Terminal to run the code?

Comment: @BlackMath He said he is using GCC which is the name of the compiler. If you compile C++ with it then you use the `g++` command which is part of GCC. In essence you copy his existing call (`g++ -std=c++17 -O3 -march=native`) and simply add `-fopenmp`.

Comment: Sorry, that was just a typo/thinko.  I meant `g++`, of course.

Comment: Same comment as on the other answer: don't use `static` for linkage, it's a C-ism.

Comment: Yuri, Thanks for the explanation. Toby,  do you use the default compiler on Linux? I mean, can I just copy and paste your command to the Terminal on Ubuntu, and it will work, without me having to install anything external?

Comment: Yes, if you have installed `g++`, then there's nothing extra required to use OpenMP - it's a standard that's implemented by the compiler and the standard library.  But you might want to add some options for warnings (I normally have at least `-Wall -Wextra -Wwrite-strings`) and perhaps enable debugging symbols (`-g`) and specify an output filename (`-o my_program`) and so on...

Comment: @Toby Appending `-fopenmp` to the command you gave gives me an error saying that `cannot find -lpthread`. What does that mean? How can I fix this? I am able to run the command without `-fopenmp` successfully.

Comment: OK, I found the solution. The package pthread wasn't installed, so I installed it, and then it worked. Thanks

Comment: My idea re. `cdf` didn't produce anything [and I tried about 5 variants]. But, I did get a 2-3x speedup by precaching the `pdf` values. I've posted an answer on this.

Comment: @Toby On my laptop, this code gives 2x speed factor over the original code. How long did the original code take on your machine for du = 0.001? On my laptop your code took around 1min 9 sec, while the original took 2mins and 18 secs.

Comment: For me, the original took over 50 seconds at that `du`, down to about 9 seconds with my reworked code.  That's on a i7-7700 processor, which may give better thread-scaling than your laptop (laptops tend to have less thermal headroom, even if thy have plenty of cores).

Answer (score 2):

I got some speedup by replacing `pow(u,2)` with `u * u`. Time for `i == 0` went from 33 sec to 26 sec.

It can be noted that `pdf(u)` is `h` *invariant* [unlike `cdf(h - u)`].

So, at each integral level `pdf(u)` can be *cached* and *only* calculated once.  This is akin to *memoization* in dynamic programming.

By doing this, I reduced the runtime to 12 sec. That is, it is 2.75x faster than the original

Note that on the first call to `pdf(u)`, `u` will be 0. It follows the sequence: `0, du, 2*du, ..., iter*du` where `iter` is the iteration index of the loop.

This is true *regardless* of what level integral we're calculating. The `pdf` sequence will *always* be the same.

So, we can keep track of the largest `iter` index we've seen. If the current index is greater than the largest, we do: `pdf_cache[iter] = pdf(u)`. Otherwise, we use `pdf_cache[iter]`.

See the code below for full details.

As a possible alternative, the `pdf_cache` array could be fully precalculated *once* before starting *anything*. Then, *all* usage of `pdf(u)` could be replaced with `pdf_cache[i]`.

This could be done in `main` before its `for` loop as `pdf_cache` will be the same no matter what `main`'s values for `i` or `gammath` (aka `h`) are.

Further, this precalculation could be split up amongst multiple cores if needed.

Also, if `openmp` is used within `integ` [as others have suggested], the full precalculation would probably be necessary to prevent interthread write contention.

**Edit:** I added this version as an update at the bottom

---

Here is the code. Please pardon the C-like stuff. This is also a prototype level.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

double
tvgetf(void)
{
    struct timespec ts;
    double sec;

    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME,&ts);
    sec = ts.tv_nsec;
    sec /= 1e9;
    sec += ts.tv_sec;

    return sec;
}

#define inline_always   static inline __attribute__((__always_inline__))

// NOTE: the size of pdf_cache is _hardwired_. The max size _can_ be calculated
// and this can become a pointer to an allocated area
int pdf_max;
float pdf_cache[10000000];

inline_always float
pdf(float u)
{
    //u += 1;
    return (1 / (u * u));
}

inline_always float
cdf(float u)
{
    u += 1;
    return (1 - 1 / (u));
}

inline_always float
pdfx(float u,int i)
{
    //u += 1;
    if (i > pdf_max) {
        pdf_cache[i] = pdf(u);
        pdf_max = i;
    }
    return pdf_cache[i];
}

// The main function that implements the numerical integration,
//and it is a recursive function
float
integ(float h, int k, float du)
{
    float res = 0;
    float u = 1;
    int i;

    int iter = h / du;

    k -= 1;

    h += 1;

    if (k == 1) {
        for (i = 0;  i < iter;  ++i) {
            res += cdf(h - u) * pdfx(u,i) * du;
            u += du;
        }
    }
    else {
        for (i = 0;  i < iter;  ++i) {
            res += integ(h - u, k, du) * pdfx(u,i) * du;
            u += du;
        }
    }

    return res;
}

// The main function that implements the numerical integration,
//and it is a recursive function
float
integ_top(float h, int k, float du)
{
    float res = 0;

    pdf_max = -1;

    if (k == 1)
        res = cdf(h);
    else
        res = integ(h,k,du);

    return res;
}

int
main()
{
    float du = 0.0001;
    int K = 3;

    float gamma[4] = { 0.31622777, 0.79432823,
        1.99526231, 5.01187234
    };
    int G = 50;
    int Q = 2;

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        if ((G - Q * (K - 1)) > 0) {
            float gammath = (gamma[i] / Q) * (G - Q * (K - 1));

            double tvbeg = tvgetf();
            double rtn = 1 - integ_top(gammath, K, du);
            //std::cout << 1 - integ(gammath, K, du) << endl;
            double tvdif = tvgetf() - tvbeg;

            printf("i=%d rtn=%f tvdif=%.9f\n",i,rtn,tvdif);
            fflush(stdout);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

---

This technique may have some roundoff error as I ran the original and got:

```
i=0 rtn=0.418665 tvdif=27.172003746
i=1 rtn=0.183092 tvdif=168.498732328
```

The cached version output was:

```
i=0 rtn=0.418630 tvdif=13.691759109
i=1 rtn=0.183040 tvdif=85.953905582
i=2 rtn=0.070858 tvdif=526.217260361
```

This might be alleviated by using `double` for the `pdf_cache` array

---

**UPDATE:**

Here is a version that precalculates the `pdf_cache` values (again, please pardon the C-like stuff):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

double
tvgetf(void)
{
    struct timespec ts;
    double sec;

    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME,&ts);
    sec = ts.tv_nsec;
    sec /= 1e9;
    sec += ts.tv_sec;

    return sec;
}

#define inline_always   static inline __attribute__((__always_inline__))

// NOTE: the size of pdf_cache is _hardwired_. The max size _can_ be calculated
// and this can become a pointer to an allocated area
int pdf_max;
float *pdf_cache;

inline_always float
pdf(float u)
{
    //u += 1;
    return (1 / (u * u));
}

inline_always float
cdf(float u)
{
    u += 1;
    return (1 - 1 / (u));
}

inline_always float
pdfx(float u,int i)
{
    //u += 1;
    if (i > pdf_max) {
        pdf_cache[i] = pdf(u);
        pdf_max = i;
    }
    return pdf_cache[i];
}

// The main function that implements the numerical integration,
//and it is a recursive function
float
integ(float h, int k, float du)
{
    float res = 0;
    float u = 1;
    int i;

    int iter = h / du;

    k -= 1;

    h += 1;

    if (k == 1) {
        for (i = 0;  i < iter;  ++i) {
            res += cdf(h - u) * pdf_cache[i] * du;
            u += du;
        }
    }
    else {
        for (i = 0;  i < iter;  ++i) {
            res += integ(h - u, k, du) * pdf_cache[i] * du;
            u += du;
        }
    }

    return res;
}

// The main function that implements the numerical integration,
//and it is a recursive function
float
integ_top(float h, int k, float du)
{
    float res = 0;

    if (k == 1)
        res = cdf(h);
    else
        res = integ(h,k,du);

    return res;
}

int
main()
{
    float du = 0.0001;
    int K = 3;

    float gamma[4] = { 0.31622777, 0.79432823,
        1.99526231, 5.01187234
    };
    int G = 50;
    int Q = 2;

    float maxgam = 0;
    int initflg = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        if ((G - Q * (K - 1)) > 0) {
            float gammath = (gamma[i] / Q) * (G - Q * (K - 1));
            printf("i=%d gammath=%f\n",i,gammath);

            if (initflg) {
                maxgam = gammath;
                initflg = 0;
                continue;
            }

            if (gammath > maxgam)
                maxgam = gammath;
        }
    }

    pdf_max = maxgam / du;
    printf("pdf_max=%d\n",pdf_max);
    pdf_cache = (float *) malloc(sizeof(*pdf_cache) * pdf_max);

    float u = 1;
    for (int i = 0;  i < pdf_max;  ++i) {
        pdf_cache[i] = pdf(u);
        u += du;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        if ((G - Q * (K - 1)) > 0) {
            float gammath = (gamma[i] / Q) * (G - Q * (K - 1));

            double tvbeg = tvgetf();
            double rtn = 1 - integ_top(gammath, K, du);
            //std::cout << 1 - integ(gammath, K, du) << endl;
            double tvdif = tvgetf() - tvbeg;

            printf("i=%d rtn=%f tvdif=%.9f\n",i,rtn,tvdif);
            fflush(stdout);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Interesting observations. I am not familiar with C, but do you have a rough total speed up factor compared to the original? `du=0.01` should run fast, but will give some insights.

Comment: This _is_ compiled in `c++` [a superset of `c`] and at a lower level they overlap and are compatible [arguably]. I just added the `malloc/printf` [which works in `c++` but is more idiomatic in `c`] (e.g. it's not the "pythonic" way but it works :-). Otherwise, all the other code here is interchangeable. And, the bulk of your code, `integ`, `cdf`, `pdf` are c/c++ agnostic. So, as above, the final benchmark is 2.75x faster than your original [where all I did was add benchmarking code] on a single core. My final version can be combined with the multicore stuff of others to get the best of both

Comment: For the largest `gammath`, the `pdf_cache` max size is about 1M elements. At 4 bytes / entry, this about 4MB. This fits within the cache memory of most x86 CPUs, so most access to it will come from the faster cache memory rather than the slower DRAM. On each loop, the `pdf_cache` element fetch is faster than recalc of `pdf` (i.e. it eliminates a floating point add, multiply, and divide on each iteration).